# Ways to place n non-attacking rooks on an $n^2$ square board.

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

How many ways are there that we can place n number of non-attacking rooks on an $n \times n$ chess board?

Comment: Another method would be to observe, that rooks at chessboard look exactly the same as [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), and any permutation matrix can be used to create rook placement, hence $n!$. BTW Wikipedia has quite nice article on [rook polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial).

Comment: See if this helps http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Rooks_on_a_chessboard_in_non_attacking_positions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume the chessboard is **oriented**. So there are two players $A$ and $B$ sitting at the board. Then the calculation is simple. We must put a rook in each row. There are $n$ locations for a rook on the top row.

For each such location, there are $n-1$ possible locations for the rook in the second row. Once we have chosen the locations for the rools in the top two rows, there are $n-2$ allowed locations for the rook on the third row, and so on, for a total of $n!$ ways.

Things get much more complicated if we consider two arrangements that look the same if the two players trade places to be the same.

Comment: I find the mention of $A\leftrightarrow B$ symmetry mostly confusing. There is no indication that OP is asking about configurations modulo symmetry. And even if that were the case, there is a symmetry group of order eight of the chessboard, and I don't see why one would focus on a specific subgroup of order$~2$ (and does one take its non-trivial element to be a reflection or a rotation)? Counting under symmetry can be handled by Burnside's lemma, but I think it would be better not to mention it at all.

Comment: I was thinking of an actual chessboard, with coloured squares.